# Send HTML code to gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, gmail

I am writing this code so that when someone wants to send an email using Gmail then they can just use the link template and an automatic email is prepared, so the function is:

```
            var sendGmail = function(opts){
    var str = 'http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1'+
              '&to=' + opts.to +
              '&su=' + opts.subject +
              '&body=' + opts.message.replace(/\n/g,'%0A') +
              '&ui=1';
    location.href = str;
}
            sendGmail({
    to: 'somename@email.com',
    subject: 'Invice number: '+value,
    message: 'Poštovani, \n'+
            ' \n'+
             'Dostavljamo Vam račun za isporučene usluge \n'+
             'Račun je automatski generisan obradom podataka i važeći je bez pečata i potpisa \n'+
             ' \n'+
             '*račun u papirnom obliku šaljemo Vam na zahtev \n'+
             ' \n'+
             'Ovo je link na kome mozete racun skinuti u PDF formatu: http://agroagro.com/netRacuni/tcpdf/examples/pdf.php?kljuc='+data+' \n' +
' \n'+
' \n'+
' \n'+
'Srdačan pozdrav i hvala na ukazanom poverenju. \n'
});
```

And this code works fine for plain a text email, but how I can send HTML to gmail to create a HTML based email template?

Is that possible with this way?

I tried:

```
sendGmail({
        to: 'somename@email.com',
        subject: 'Invice number: '+value,
        message: '<h1>Poštovani </h1> etc....
```

But this doesn't work. How I can send HTML code to gmail to render that as HTML and not as plain text?

Comment: you need to set header type as html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the answers no

**Rule Number 1: Security**

**Vulnerabilities Explained:**
For security reasons all html from the URL will be stripped. Google takes security in mind and therefore html entities will be removed.

The function in php which removes the html entities is..

htmlspecialchars($string);

And i'm sure gmail will do something similar to this function.

If you send a message with the url containing the code below, the website is essentially hacked or looks hacked...

```
<script>
alert('You have been hacked');
</script>
```

this code could be run like....

```
example.com/?email=<script>alert('hacked');</script>
```

or replacing "<" and ">" with html entity codes

And that's the reason it is not possible.

Your best option is to use a server side language. Such as php to send your mail as html. The mail() function will be a good place to start. Referece: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
Remember to change the header-type to render the email as html.

Comment: Ok, I use that and its ok. But somethimes for my user is easier to use personal gmail account... so thanks I will continou using plain text for gmail emails

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness you could always send the email using php to a specific email address. For example.. $to="name@example.com";mail($to, $subject, $message); Also, please mark the answer as answered if it has answered your question so other users can use the answer. Thanks